# In Dajngo, does the UserCreationForm or its parent classes handle the POST and GET logic? Or how is that handled?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new with django and going over some code that I don't understand. I looked through the django source code trying to find out if the class `UserCreationFrom` (pasted below) from Django handles the logic of POST for you, or if this is implemented elsewhere.

To clarify, I have been seeing a class used for rendering the form then some type of view validating the data. It typically goes like:

Form Class:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ("first_name", "last_name")
```

View:

```
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        return redirect("somewhere")
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, "profile.html", {"user_form":user_form})
```

That implementation makes sense.

What I don't get is when there is a view that renders the form but then the form itself handles validation and leaves out the `if request.method == "POST"` logic as shown above. Or is this in some parent class? Is either one of these inline with django convention as well?

An example:

Class View:

```
class UserSignupView(CreateView):
    model = CustomUser
    form_class = UserProfileSignupForm
    template_name = 'signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['is_confused'] = True
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('somewhere')
```

Then the form with its logic would be like:

```
class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
       model = User

   def save(self):
         user = super().save(commit=False)
         user.is_confused = True
         user.save()
         return user
```

Any advice and clarification is greatly appreciated.

Like I said, I've looked through the django docs and cannot figure this out. I think I'm missing something basic or if the code I have doesn't present the full story here. To clarify the following forms are to the same thing though they are not for an identical purpose. I got one from one model/app and the other from another. I assume either could be modified slightly and used wherever this functionality is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Django Form does not handle GET vs POST logic, that's usually handled by the view.

The user forms are handled by the login/logout view in the [auth views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views).

You can use:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

to include all the authentication view in their standard locations, or you can add the individual views into your urls.py (e.g. LoginView and friends) for more fine grained control.

These class-based views inherits from the [generic form handling class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) and/or [generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/).

Ultimately, the way class based view works is that they're really just regular function based views under the hood, but they were implemented as a class which provides some common logic and some hook functions that you can override to customise the generic behaviour.

Comment: That makes more sense. I was missing the main idea it seems. Thank you!